# Hi there, I'm using Oracle. I want to create a view where in this view, I display the rows of the same primary key and the total number of coin sales

Tags: oracle

There's a couple of tables that I need to use columns from in the select statement. the questions is: **Create a View to display the employee id, first name and surname. In your query include the coin price and a 10% commission for the sales made by the employees.**

the difficult part for me is that employees of the same employee number, can make multiple coin sales, so in the view, i need to be able to add all the coin sales together of each respective primary key (employee_id)

[image]

As you can see in this image, emp101 has sold two different coins, with the coin_id's of "7116" and "7112". In the view i want to be able to somehow tally each coin value that each employee_id has sold if that makes sense ?

There's multiple other tables, but there's too many to send, so i am just trying to get a general idea of how to do this. I understand the logistics of the question, i just dont know how to implement the answer with the correct syntax and methods etc...

Answer (score 0):

Since this appears to be a homework question, here is a discussion of how to solve it:

You want to `CREATE` a `VIEW` and give the view a name (something like `employee_commisions`) and include 5 columns (`employee_id`, `first_name`, `surname`, `coin_price` and `commission` - or maybe only 4 columns if they want the combined price plus commission).

To get the values for that view, you want to `SELECT ... FROM` existing tables; however, your image does not include `first_name`, `surname` or a value for a coin so I am assuming that you will have an `employees` table and a `coins` table that you will need to `INNER JOIN` to the `invoice` table on their respective primary keys.

To get the total value for the coins, you want to aggregate the values and this would be done with the `SUM` aggregation function and, so that you get the value for each employee, you would need to `GROUP BY` the `employee_id` primary key. You will either need to include the other columns you are not aggregating by in the `GROUP BY` clause or apply an aggregation function to those columns such as `MAX(surname)`.

The syntax for `CREATE VIEW` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html).

The syntax for `SELECT` is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html).

Comment: thank you so much man!! really appreciate the answer

Comment: @AdamBarnard - glad you got a solution.  In the future, please do not make people surmise about the tables and data involved. Please read about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)